# How can I prevent a table's text in a 2 column table from pushing the cell below it to the other side?

Tags: html, css

Just to warn you, I have almost no experience coding anything. Anyways, I downloaded this template to create a newsletter but I if I add too much text in one section, it can push the next section to a weird space. I can solve it by reversing the left/right alignment of the two cells beneath it, but I would like the cell to just be pushed down, and not to the left or right.

Image included to show the error. [Columns all wonky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fXeY.png)
How can I fix this?

```css
.header,
.title,
.subtitle,
.footer-text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  color: #505050;
}

.footer-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
.footer-text a {
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.container-padding {
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

code {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0 4px;
  font-family: Menlo, Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

a {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #a6192e;
}

.hr {
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #404040;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #a6192e;
}
.subtitle span {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #999999;
}

.body-text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #404040;
}

.col {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333333;
  width: 100%;
}

a[href^="x-apple-data-detectors:"],
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit !important;
  font-weight: inherit !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
   <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
   </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  </xml><![endif]-->
  <!-- fix outlook zooming on 120 DPI windows devices -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- So that mobile will display zoomed in -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- enable media queries for windows phone 8 -->
  <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no"> <!-- disable auto date linking in iOS 7-9 -->
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> <!-- disable auto telephone linking in iOS 7-9 -->
  <title>Two Columns to Rows (Simple)</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
    <style type="text/css">a {text-decoration: none}</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

<!-- 100% background wrapper (grey background) -->
<table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#F0F0F0" style="background-color: #F0F0F0;">

      <br>

      <!-- 600px container (white background) -->
      <table border="0" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container">
        <tr>
          <td class="container-padding header" align="left">
            Student Update August 29
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="container-padding content" align="left">
            <br>
<div class="title">Academic Advising</div>
<br>

<div class="body-text">
        Academic advising for the Faculty of Environment <a href="http://www.sfu.ca/fenv/students/current-students/undergraduate-students/advising.html" style="text-decoration: none">HERE</a>
  <br><br>
</div>

<div class="hr">&nbsp;</div>
<br>

<!-- example: two columns (simple) -->

<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

    <table width="264" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="force-row">
      <tr>
        <td class="col" valign="top">
        <div class="subtitle">
             <strong>Herman Melville</strong>
        </div>
          <br>
          It's worse than being in the whirled woods, the last day of the year! Who'd go climbing after chestnuts now? But there they go, all cursing, and here I don't.          It's worse than being in the whirled woods, the last day of the year! Who'd go climbing after chestnuts now? But there they go, all cursing, and here I don't.
          It's worse than being in the whirled woods, the last day of the year! Who'd go climbing after chestnuts now? But there they go, all cursing, and here I don't.

          <br><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!--[if mso]></td><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

    <table width="264" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="force-row">
      <tr>
        <td class="col" valign="top">
        <div class="subtitle">
            <strong>I am Ishmael</strong>
        </div>
        <br>
        White squalls? white whale, shirr! shirr! Here have I heard all their chat just now, and the white whale—shirr! shirr!—but spoken of once! and&hellip;         White squalls? white whale, shirr! shirr! Here have I heard all their chat just now, and the white whale—shirr! shirr!—but spoken of once! and&hellip; 

        <br><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
              
   <!--[if mso]></td><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

    <table width="264" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="force-row">
      <tr>
        <td class="col" valign="top">
        <div class="subtitle">
            <strong>I am Ishmael</strong>
        </div>
        <br>
        White squalls? white whale, shirr! shirr! Here have I heard all their chat just now, and the white whale—shirr! shirr!—but spoken of once! and&hellip;
        <br><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
              
       <!--[if mso]></td><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

    <table width="264" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="force-row">
      <tr>
        <td class="col" valign="top">
        <div class="subtitle">
            <strong>I am Ishmael</strong>
        </div>
        <br>
        sdsaddasdadas

        <br><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if mso]></td><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

    <table width="264" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="force-row">
      <tr>
        <td class="col" valign="top">
        <div class="subtitle">
            <strong>I am Ishmael</strong>
        </div>
        <br>
        White squalls? white whale, shirr! shirr! Here have I heard all their chat just now, and the white whale—shirr! shirr!—but spoken of once! and&hellip;
        <br><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
                  <!--[if mso]></td><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

    <table width="264" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="force-row">
      <tr>
        <td class="col" valign="top">
        <div class="subtitle">
            <strong>I am Ishmael</strong>
        </div>
        <br>
        White squalls? white whale, shirr! shirr! Here have I heard all their chat just now, and the white whale—shirr! shirr!—but spoken of once! and&hellip;
        <br><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->


<!--/ end example -->

<div class="hr" style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
<br>

<div class="subtitle">
  Code Walkthrough
</div>

<div class="body-text">
  <ol>
    <li>
      Create a columns container <code>&lt;table&gt;</code> just for Outlook using <code>if mso</code> conditionals.<br>
      The container's <code>&lt;td&gt;</code>'s have a width of <code>50%.</code>
      <br><br>
    </li>
    <li>
      Wrap our columns in a <code>&lt;table&gt;</code> with a <strong>fixed width</strong> of <code>264px</code>.
      <ul>
        <li>
          264px = (600 - 24*3) / 2 - container width minus margins divided by number of columns
        </li>
        <li>
          First table is aligned left.
        </li>
        <li>
          Second table is aligned right.
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br>
    </li>
    <li>
      Apply <code>clear: both;</code> to first element after our wrapper table.
    </li>
  </ol>


</div>

<br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="container-padding footer-text" align="left">
            <br>

            <br>
            <span class="ios-footer">
                Faculty of Environment<br>
                TASC2 Suite 8800<br>
              Burnaby V5A 1S6<br>
            </span>
            <a href="http://www.sfu.ca/fenv">www.sfu.ca/fenv</a><br>

            <br><br>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table><!--/600px container -->


    </td>
  </tr>
</table><!--/100% background wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you narrow down your code to the problem area

Comment: The problem starts here: 
 
<!-- example: two columns (simple) -->

<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr><td width="50%" valign="top"><![endif]-->

    <table width="264" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="force-row">
      <tr>
<br>
I'm not sure how to shorten it more and still make it understandable? If you run the code you should be able to see my issue.